# Why doesn't floor return an integer?

Tags: c++, c

Just now I stumbled upon the fact, that the C++ function `floor` returns the same type you pass to it, be it `float`, `double` or such.

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/floor/), the function returns a down rounded integral value. Why isn't this an integer?

Comment: Presumably for the same reason as [tag:c].

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511921/why-does-math-floor-return-a-double

Comment: What is your practical programming problem? Do you need a version of `floor` that returns an int?

Comment: It is a duplicate. Unfortunately, this one has a better answer than the one it's a dupe of.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Because an integral type can't necessarily hold the same integral values as a `float` or `double`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << floor(std::numeric_limits<float>::max()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_cast<long>(floor(std::numeric_limits<float>::max())) << ::endl;
}
```

outputs (on my x86_64 architecture)

```
3.40282e+38
-9223372036854775808
```

Additionally, floating-point values can hold NaN, +Inf, and -Inf, all of which are preserved by a `floor()` operation. None of these values can be represented with an integral type.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::cout << floor(std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << floor(std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << floor(-std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) << std::endl;
}
```

outputs

```
nan
inf
-inf
```

Comment: +1 for the illustration.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer in the dupe.